# SharepointFramework - how to set the actual webpart code as initial value in PropertyFieldCodeEditor

Tags: spfx, sharepointframework

Hello i am using this custom property pane control called PropertyFieldCodeEditor. what i want is to display the actual webpart code as the initial value of the code editor, then after i click save, the changes will be reflected on the webpart..

this is the code of PropertyFieldCodeEditor

```
PropertyFieldCodeEditor('htmlCode', {
    label: 'Edit Code',
    panelTitle: 'Edit Code',
    initialValue: "",
    onPropertyChange: this.onPropertyPaneFieldChanged,
    properties: this.properties,
    disabled: false,
    key: 'codeEditorFieldId',
    language: PropertyFieldCodeEditorLanguages.HTML
  })
```

i tried to put `this.domElement` on initialvalue but it only accept string, also i cand find a way to convert  `this.domelement` to string..

also what should i put inside

```
protected onPropertyPaneFieldChanged(path: string, newValue: string) {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `initialValue`, you should be able to use `this.domElement.innerHTML` or `this.domElement.outerHTML`. Both are strings representing the contents of `domElement` (note, `domElement` is really just an [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement)).

- `outerHTML` will include everything, including one extra `div` layer on the outside:

```js
<div style="width: 100%;">
  <div class="helloWorld_d3285de8">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

- `innerHTML` is only the inside contents of that `div`:

```js
<div class="helloWorld_d3285de8">
  ...
</div>
```

You'll probably want `innerHTML`, since that's what's initially used in the `render` method.

Once you set the `initialValue`, you would have accomplished copying your web part code into the `PropertyFieldCodeEditor`. Now you would need to get the `PropertyFieldCodeEditor` contents (which is stored in your property `htmlCode`) assigned back into `this.domElement.innerHTML`.

Unfortunately, in `onPropertyPaneFieldChanged`, `this` points to the `PropertyFieldCodeEditor`, not to the web part class anymore. You may or may not be able to do it here - I didn't look too deeply into it.

The easiest solution I figured was, in `render`, to assign `this.domElement.innerHTML` like so:

```js
public render(): void {
  this.domElement.innerHTML = this.properties.htmlCode || `
    <div class="${styles.helloWorld}">
      ...
    </div>`;
}
```

This way, the web part will initially render whatever comes after the `||`. But as soon as you save a change to the `PropertyFieldCodeEditor`, it will start rendering the `htmlCode` instead. This only works because initially `htmlCode` is `undefined`. (Note it won't work exactly like this if you assign something truthy to it via your web part's [`preconfiguredEntries`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/simplify-adding-web-parts-with-preconfigured-entries) - you would have to write some further checks. The principle is the same, though.)

Comment: the innerHTML works, but the code is rendered on a single line.. how do i make it look like a real code w/ proper indentation? i have read the documentation but couldnt fine any clue

Comment: Where do you mean is the code being rendered? In the PropertyFieldCodeEditor, or in the web part?

Comment: In the PropertyFieldCodeEditor, the code was displayed in single line

Comment: Make sure to click on the PropertyFieldCodeEditor to open a second pane to edit the code. If it's still in a single line on this second pane - maybe try switching between LF/CRLF line endings to see if that makes a difference?